# Partially transparent div in css

Tags: html, css

I have a background image and a div that comes on top of that. I want the other div to be transparent (partially) so that I can still see the background below it with some opacity (if possible). I am new to CSS so any help would be great.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try `.div{opacity:.5}` ?

Comment: Thanks Akshay, its a nice suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put this in the top div that you have.

```
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the css property opacity to set the level of transparency of the div in question. Example:

```
#transparent-div{
opacity:0.4;
}
```

The opacity property works on a scale between 0 and 1 with 1 being completely opaque and 0 being completely transparent.